# App Engine query for all objects with an existing property

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'd like to do a query that returns all entities for which a particular property exists.  I don't care about the vale of the property, just that it exists.  What is a good way to do this on python for app engine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Filtering Or Sorting On a Property Requires That the Property Exists**
>
> If a property has a query filter condition or sort order, the query returns only those datastore entities that have a value (including null) for that property.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Restrictions_on_Queries

So just sort your results by the field you want to check for existence.